# How I can check the status of AWS Glacier archive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I just noticed that after uploading an archive to a Glacier vault (using java code), it takes time until the archive is available for download again.
Is there any way to query the status of the uploaded archive?
The final purpose for me is to upload backups from different computers and in case of corruption, I need to download and restore the data in this archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information about a job previously initiated,  using AWS CLI's `aws glacier describe-job` command.
Refer [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glacier/describe-job.html) for the details.